# Run an exe from C#

Tags: c#, exe

i have a problem to call PsService from C# code.
when i wrote `psservice \\ip -u user -p Calendar# restart spooler`(init.txt) from cmd it's ok, but in C# i had problem. my code :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = @"C:\exe\PsService";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\exe\init.txt";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```

then i run bin\debug\myExe  from cmd but wrote this:

> Use the username and password to log into remote computer in cases
>   where you account does not have permissions to perform the action you
>   specify.

Comment: Windows may be picky when starting exe file from the OS drive (C:).  Have you tried moving the file on a other drive, or starting your application as administrator?

Comment: You're missing ".exe" from your `FileName` and you do not pass the arguments as shown ("-u user").

Comment: Why do you expect `startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\exe\init.txt";` to pass `init.txt`'s _contents_ to the executable? That's not how it works, and PsService also doesn't read parameters from a passed filename.

Comment: and how can i pass  'psservice \\ip -u user -p Calendar# restart spooler' this code to PsService from C# ?

Comment: @CodeCaster can you help me ?

Comment: thank u all; i found out my silly mistake :/ 
 
 in Arguments i had "PsService"  and instead of [  @"\\ip -u User -p Pass restart spooler]  this i called [@" PsService \\ip -u User -p Pass restart spooler.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the cmd code works well then the easiest way is to call whatever your exe application through cmd. Don't go into mess.

`Process.start("cmd.exe","/c [enter cmd code]")`

Replace `[enter cmd code]` without square brackets [ ]

Answer (score 0):

i had a silly mistake :)

```
   startInfo.FileName = @"C:\exe\PsService";
   startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\exe\init.txt";
```

in `init.txt` i had `psservice \\ip -u user -p Calendar# restart spooler` and
`psservice` was exrta :)